# WCF: The Caller was not authenticated by the service

Tags: wcf

I have just configured my first service application and i am getting this error:

"The Caller was not authenticated by the service."

The service is being hosted on my server via IIS 6.0 and I have created a desktop application on another pc which consumes this service. The strange thing is when the two applications are on the same PC the service works. I have anonymous user access enabled on IIS. Iv been looking at this for some time now and I still have no idea how to configure my service and my client application correctly in order for them to interact.

Please Help!!

Regards

James

Server web config:

Clint App Config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <netNamedPipeBinding>
            <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICOPITSERVICE" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netNamedPipeBinding>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                transactionFlow="false" transferMode="Buffered" transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" listenBacklog="10"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxBufferSize="65536" maxConnections="10"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="WSHttpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                allowCookies="false">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                    enabled="false" />
                <security mode="Message">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                        algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/COPIT_SERVICE/ws" binding="wsHttpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE" contract="COPIT_SERVICE.ICOPITSERVICE"
            name="WSHttpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE">
            <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/COPIT_SERVICE/basic"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE"
            contract="COPIT_SERVICE.ICOPITSERVICE" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE" />
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8888/COPIT_SERVICE" binding="netTcpBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE" contract="COPIT_SERVICE.ICOPITSERVICE"
            name="NetTcpBinding_ICOPITSERVICE">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="jscott@afis.ad.ucc.ie" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/COPIT_SERVICE" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
            bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICOPITSERVICE" contract="COPIT_SERVICE.ICOPITSERVICE"
            name="NetNamedPipeBinding_ICOPITSERVICE">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="jscott@afis.ad.ucc.ie" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: and which endpoint are you using in your case?

Answer (score 0):

As marc_s says, which binding are you using.

There are however several things here that will not work:

- netNamedPipes and netTCP bindings are not supported using IIS 6.
- netNamedPipe binding will not work between machines. This is by design.

I am guessing that you are using the wsHttpBinding, this is using a windows credential. There are then 2-3 possible problems:

- The anonymous IIS setting results in the client not being authenticated
- The machines are not in a domain
- The client is logged in with a local account